# Microstrategy 10.4 SQL ODBC Connection error

Tags: sql-server, odbc, microstrategy

I've tried to connect an SQL database from a server with Microstrategy located in another server through an ODBC connector for SQL.
First I've checked that there is a connection between the two servers executing a ping sentence with the IP Address the other server and it went through.
After making sure the connection is stablished without issues, I've tried to connect through Microstrategy without success. The error I get is the following message:

"Connection test error: Connect failed. Error type Odbc error. Odbc operation attempted: SQLDriverConnect (08001:0: on SQLHANDLE)"

Using SQL Server 2017 for the databases and Microstrategy 10.4.

Please, anybody has any clue about what might be happening?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

look at the type of connector to the db you have. It gave me the same error until I used: "with Native Client Driver".

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share the complete error message, **SQL Handle error** are associated with multiple error scenarios like invalid username * password, connecting 64 bit server with 32 bit ODBC driver etc. Complete error message would help me to debug it.

In general follow the steps to debug the error, (any order)

- Check the version of ODBC Connection (64bit / 32 bit), it should be the same as server version.
- Try testing the ODBC connection that you have created using ODBC Administrator tools to see whether there is an problem with username & password/server name or database connection issue.
- Check the Database Instance/Database Connection/User Login created under the Administration option to ensure everything is working and give the correct value.
- if nothing works try using the native driver given by MicroStrategy, you can access this using Connectivity Wizard.

Hope it helps..

Comment: which ODBC Administrator tool ? I'm stuck with this error since 3 days....